# How to execute JavaScript in a browser from the command prompt

Tags: javascript, windows, sublimetext2, command-prompt

I am wondering if it is possible to execute JavaScript in a browser window using the command prompt in Windows.  Is it possible to start chrome and execute a JS file in that new browser window, all from the command prompt?

Comment: take a look at userscripts (`user.js`)

Comment: It's certainly possible to open a browser to a specific page from the command line... so you could put some JavaScript in an html page and launch a browser so it opens that page.

Comment: @jahroy I've been trying for over 30 minutes to achieve something like this as a _.bat_ for an answer (anon func takes `window.location.search` and adds as `<script>`), but DOS just keeps tripping up over strings. Long story short; write a `.html` file to do it.

Comment: Wow... I can't think of anything worse that working with _.bat_ files!

Comment: You could look at Adobe AIR. Gives you a Webkit wrapper you can write JS for.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it.

I just tried this though:

You can put `javascript:alert("moo")` in the browser's home page url setting, which will run as soon as you open the browser.